# Kubernetes Cronjobs leave the pod behind in Not Ready State after getting Completed

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

Recently all the cronjobs on my GKE cluster started showing some weird behaviour. With all the configurations remaining same for the cronjobs, out of nowhere, now my cronjobs are getting triggered, executed & completed but the Pod is left behind in a Not Ready state. I've been using ***successfulJobsHistoryLimit*** and ***failedJobsHistoryLimit*** as ***0***. Also, tried ***concurrencyPolicy***: ***"Replace"*** and ***spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished***: ***1*** but still nothing changed. I want to get rid of these as there are some crons running at every 5 minutes and so, generating huge list of not ready completed pods here when I run ***kubectl get pods***

```
NAME                            READY    STATUS        RESTARTS      AGE
my-cron-27711665-gjdk4          0/1      Completed     0             46m
```

Here's the ***cronjob.yaml*** file:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron
spec:
  schedule: "0 */1 * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: cronjob-secret
          containers:
          - name: my-cron
            image: kubernetes_cronjob_new:dev
            command: ["/bin/bash","-c"]
            args:
              - po1=$(kubectl get pods  | awk '/mybackend/ {printf($1);exit}');
                kubectl exec -i $po1 -- python manage.py run_cron my_cron False;
                exit 0;
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Currently working on ***Kubernetes Version: 1.22***

Can anyone help me here? How to get rid of these or why this started happening all of sudden?

Comment: share yor yaml file for ref and k8s version that you are using, would be difficult for anyone to answer without much details or file ref.

Comment: Okay sure, I'll add those as well

Comment: Can you share your Error logs details for reference.